# Missy Elliot, XKCD and ASCII Bytes

Tags: code-golf, printable-ascii

Inspired by the following XKCD comic:

[image]

In Missy Elliot's "Work It", part of the chorus goes as follows:

`Is it worth it, let me work it`

`I put my thing down, flip it and reverse it`

Bearing that in mind, I propose the following code golf challenge:

Create code that does, in order:

1. Takes 8-bit ASCII input from STDIN; e.g `n` (Hex 6E, or Bin
   01101110)
2. Shifts each byte's 8 bits down 1 bit level (I believe it's called a
   bitwise shift down), e.g `01101110` becomes `00110111` ("put my
   thing down");
3. Inverts each byte's bits, e.g `00110111` becomes `11001000` ("flip
   it");
4. Reverses the bits for each byte, e.g `11001000` becomes `00010011`
   ("reverse it");
5. If a byte's value is less than 32, then perform `(95 + [byte value])`,
   or in other words, `(126-(31-[byte value]))`, on the byte before
   converting back to ASCII... If the byte value is still less than 32, repeat step 5
6. If a byte's value is greater than 126, then perform `([byte value] - 95)`, or in other words, `(32+([byte value]-127))`, on the byte before
   converting back to ASCII... IF the value is still greater than 126, repeat step 6.
7. Display the newly converted string as ASCII.

**An example of this code in action:**

(The input, is it worth it?)

`workit missy` ("missy" being the input, "workit" is the function)

*Now behind the scenes...*

(let me work it... Into binary)

`01101101 01101001 01110011 01110011 01111001`

(Put my thing down... Bitwise)

`00110110 00110100 00111001 00111001 00111100`

(...Flip it...)

`11001001 11001011 11000110 11000110 11000011`

(... And reverse it!)

`10010011 11010011 01100011 01100011 11000011`

(Converted back to Decimal)

`147 211 99 99 195`

(Perform the necessary math)

`147-95 211-95 99 99 195-95 => 52 116 99 99 100`

(Convert back to ASCII and display, the output)

`4tccd`

**Rules**

1. Shortest code wins... simple as that...
2. Input can be via function, by prompt or whatever works for you, so long as you can make Rule 1 "work it" for you... ;)
3. I am not after reversibility, so long as you can make the code do what I have asked it to do, I'll be happy...

Best of luck!

Comment: Do we care that this is not a reversible process? When the bit shift is performed the least-significant bit is essentially thrown away.

Comment: For the purpose of this exercise we are not after reversibility... We don't give a crap about it, essentially ;) I just want the code to do as I have requested...

Comment: I get `0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1`
and `0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1` for `mi`

Comment: @marinus, by golly you're right... Editing...
Okay, that's been fixed and the result modified accordingly...

Comment: I always did wonder what that song was about...

Comment: By my calcs, there are eight input ASCII chars (`A`,`P`,`Q`,`a`,`p`,`q`,`@`,`\``) that output ASCII codes > 126. i.e. "unprintable" -meh-

Comment: @DarrenStone That's why I put in the wrap around rules so that it stays within the confines of characters 32-126...

Comment: The rules do not do that, do they?  For example: `P` turns into the byte value `235` and subtracting `95` leaves you with `140`. Still unprintable. Or do I misunderstand?

Comment: Shoot, good point... I will have to alter the rule slightly...

Good point... I'll give you +1 for spotting the flaw...

Comment: Be careful altering the rules. You have a lot of submitted answers which conform to your current definition.

Answer (score 5):

### APL  <s>50</s>  45

```
⎕UCS n+95×¯1++⌿126 31∘.≥n←2⊥⊖~(8/2)⊤⌊.5×⎕UCS⍞
```

Takes input on the keyboard, e.g.:

```
      ⎕UCS n+95×¯1++⌿126 31∘.≥n←2⊥⊖~(8/2)⊤⌊.5×⎕UCS⍞
missy
4tccd
```

Comment: I took the liberty of improving your answer down to 45 (pending edit approval.) It took too much from yours to post it as my own

Answer (score 4):

### GolfScript <del>43</del> <del>38</del> 35

```
{2/~512+2base(;-1%2base-32+95%32+}%
```

Explanation:
For each character in the string, we will do the following:

```
2/ # "Put your thing down": do integer division (accomplishing a bit shift).
~ # "Flip it": negate the bits of the integer.
512+ #make sure the binary form will have sufficient initial 0s (the extra initial 1 will be removed).
2base #convert string to value in base 2 (as an array)
(; #remove the initial 1 added by the 512 addition
-1% # "Reverse it": reverse the array
2base #convert back to base 10
-32+95%32+ #this does the equivalent of the subtraction/addition logic
```

Usage:

```
echo 'missy' | ruby golfscript.rb workit.gs
> 4tccd
```

Thanks to help from PeterTaylor.

Comment: Clever, and so far you're in the lead!

Comment: I usually find that the best way to get a guaranteed number of digits when I do a base conversion is to add a suitable value beforehand. I.e. instead of `2base{0\+.,9<}do` it would be `512+2base(;`. Also note that if the intention is only to get the correct output you can reorder the operations, so rather than `{!}%` you just need to `~` the input before base conversion (and then replace the `512+` with `511&`).

Comment: Thanks @PeterTaylor - the 512 trick is perfect!  In the spirit of the question, though, I think we should bit shift before negating.

Comment: If you count `2/` as a bit shift then you can still bit shift, then `~`, then base convert...

Comment: @PeterTaylor I like it!  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

## K, <strike>68</strike> 58

```
{"c"${$[a<32;95;a>126;-95;0]+a:6h$0b/:|~8#0b,0b\:x}'4h$'x}
```

.

```
k){"c"${$[a<32;95;a>126;-95;0]+a:6h$0b/:|~8#0b,0b\:x}'4h$'x}"missy"
"4tccd"
```

Answer (score 2):

## J - 61

```
u:-&95^:(>&126)"0+&95^:(<&32)"0#.|."1(1-0,0,}:)"1#:3&u:1!:1[1
missy
4tccd
```

Answer (score 2):

## J, <strike>55</strike> 54 characters

```
u:+/(*126&>*.32&<)_95 0 95+/#.|."1#:255-<.-:a.i.1!:1[1
```

Comment: Muy impressivo!

Answer (score 1):

### Ruby, 115

This entry is uncompetitively long. So I'll go with, "but you can read it!"  :-P

```
$><<gets.chars.map{|c|c=(c.ord.to_s(2)[0..-2].tr('01','10').reverse+'11').to_i(2)
(c+(c<32?95:c>126?-95:0)).chr}*''
```

Reads from `stdin`:

```
missy
4tccd
```

Answer (score 1):

### Python 2.7, 106

Another rather long answer, but hey it's my first try:

```
for c in raw_input():x=sum(1<<7-i for i in range(8)if~ord(c)>>1+i&1);print'\b%c'%(x+95*((x<32)-(x>126))),
```

Modified based off of Darren Stone and grc's comments below...

Comment: You can drop the space after `a:`.

Comment: You can replace your final `chr` expression with this for another 1-char savings:  `chr(x-(95,(-95,0)[x>32])[x<126])`.

Comment: A bit shorter: `print'\b%c'%(x+95*((x<32)-(x>126))),`

Answer (score 1):

### Python 2.7 - 73 <del>86</del>

Thanks to the change in rules I found a much simpler way to do this all using binary and integer manipulation. This saves space over Quirlioms by not needing a temporary variable:

```
for i in input():print chr((int(bin(ord(i)>>1^255)[:1:-1],2)-32)%95+32),

> python workit.py
"missy"
4 t c c d
> python workit.py
"P Diddy"
- 9 \ t T T d
```

And in explanation form:

```
for i in input():  # Take an input, better quote it
                   # Is it worth it? Let me work it
  print chr(
    int(bin(
        ord(i)>>1  # Put my thing down by bitshifting it
             ^255  # XOR it with 255 to flip the bits and pad to 8 bits
        )[:1:-1]   # Then reverse it (but don't take the cruft
                   # python puts at the start of binary strings)
    ,2) 
    )-32)%95+32    # This pulls everything into the 32-126 range
  ),
```