# Binary encryption

Tags: code-golf, string, binary

This is based on [xkcd #153](http://xkcd.com/153/).

Make a program or named function which takes 2 parameters, each of which is a string or a list or array of bytes or characters. The second parameter will only contain characters drawn from `lrfu` (or the equivalent ASCII bytes). It should be interpreted as a series of instructions to be performed on a bit sequence represented by the first parameter.

The processing performed must be equivalent to the following:

1. Convert the first parameter into a single bitstring formed by concatenating the bits of each character (interpreted as one of 7-bit ASCII, an 8-bit extended ASCII, or a standard Unicode encoding). E.g. if the first parameter is `"AB"` then this would be one of `10000011000010` (7-bit), `0100000101000010` (8-bit or UTF-8), `00000000010000010000000001000010`, or `01000001000000000100001000000000` (UTF-16 in the two endiannesses), etc.
2. For each character in the second parameter, in order, execute the corresponding instruction:

   - `l` rotates the bitstring left one. E.g. `10000011000010` becomes `00000110000101`.
   - `r` rotates the bitstring right one. E.g. `10000011000010` becomes `01000001100001`.
   - `f` flips (or inverts) each bit in the bitstring. E.g. `10000011000010` becomes `01111100111101`.
   - `u` reverses the bitstring. E.g. `10000011000010` becomes `01000011000001`.
3. Convert the bitstring into an ASCII string which uses one character per bit. E.g. `10000011000010` becomes `"10000011000010"`. This is because not all sets of 7/8 bits have a character assigned to them.

Example (in Python):

```
>>> f("b", "rfu")
01110011
```

It turns `"b"` into its 8-bit ASCII binary representation `01100010`, rotates it right (`00110001`), flips each bit (`11001110`), and reverses it (`01110011`).

#### Flexibility

Other characters may be used instead of the characters `l`, `r`, `f`, and `u`, but they must be clearly documented.

#### Scoreboard

Thanks to [@Optimizer](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/31414/optimizer) for creating the following code snippet. To use, click "Show code snippet", scroll to the bottom and click "► Run code snippet".

```js
var QUESTION_ID = 45087; var answers = [], page = 1;var SCORE_REG = /\d+(?=[^\d&]*(?:&lt;(?:s&gt;[^&]*&lt;\/s&gt;|[^&]+&gt;)[^\d&]*)*$)/;function url(index) {return "http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/" +  QUESTION_ID + "/answers?page=" + index + "&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=votes&site=codegolf&filter=!t)IWYnsLAZle2tQ3KqrVveCRJfxcRLe";}function getAnswers() {$.ajax({url: url(page++),method: "get",dataType: "jsonp",crossDomain: true,success: function (data) {answers.push.apply(answers, data.items);if (data.has_more) getAnswers();else process()}});}getAnswers();function shouldHaveHeading(a) {var pass = false;try {pass |= /^(#|&lt;h).*/.test(a.body_markdown);pass |= ["-", "="].indexOf(a.body_markdown.split("\n")[1][0]) > -1;} catch (ex) {}return pass;}function shouldHaveScore(a) {var pass = false;try {pass |= SCORE_REG.test(a.body_markdown.split("\n")[0]);} catch (ex) {}return pass;}function getRelDate(previous) {var current = Date.now();var msPerMinute = 60 * 1000;var msPerHour = msPerMinute * 60;var msPerDay = msPerHour * 24;var msPerMonth = msPerDay * 30;var msPerYear = msPerDay * 365;var elapsed = current - previous;if (elapsed < msPerMinute) {return Math.round(elapsed/1000) + ' seconds ago';}if (elapsed < msPerHour) {return Math.round(elapsed/msPerMinute) + ' minutes ago';}if (elapsed < msPerDay ) {return Math.round(elapsed/msPerHour ) + ' hours ago';}if (elapsed < msPerMonth) {return 'approx. ' + Math.round(elapsed/msPerDay) + ' days ago';}if (elapsed < msPerYear) {return 'approx. ' + Math.round(elapsed/msPerMonth) + ' months ago';}return 'approx. ' + Math.round(elapsed/msPerYear ) + ' years ago';}function process() {answers = answers.filter(shouldHaveHeading);answers = answers.filter(shouldHaveScore);answers.sort(function (a, b) {var aB = +(a.body_markdown.split("\n")[0].match(SCORE_REG) || [Infinity])[0],bB = +(b.body_markdown.split("\n")[0].match(SCORE_REG) || [Infinity])[0];return aB - bB});answers.forEach(function (a) {var answer = $("#answer-template").html();answer = answer.replace("{{BODY}}", a.body).replace("{{NAME}}", a.owner.display_name).replace("{{REP}}", a.owner.reputation).replace("{{VOTES}}", a.score).replace("{{DATE}}", new Date(a.creation_date*1e3).toUTCString()).replace("{{REL_TIME}}", getRelDate(a.creation_date*1e3)).replace("{{POST_LINK}}", a.share_link).replace(/{{USER_LINK}}/g, a.owner.link).replace('{{img}}=""', "src=\"" + a.owner.profile_image + '"');answer = $(answer);if (a.is_accepted) {answer.find(".vote-accepted-on").removeAttr("style");}$("#answers").append(answer);});}
```

```css
body { text-align: left !important}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/codegolf/all.css?v=83c949450c8b"><div id="answers"></div><div id="answer-template" style="display: none"><div class="answer" ><table><tbody><tr><td class="votecell"><div class="vote"><span style="cursor: pointer;" title="Total Votes" itemprop="upvoteCount" class="vote-count-post ">{{VOTES}}</span><span style="display: none" class="vote-accepted-on load-accepted-answer-date" title="The question owner accepted this as the best answer">accepted</span></div></td><td class="answercell"><div class="post-text" itemprop="text">{{BODY}}</div><table class="fw"><tbody><tr><td class="vt"><div class="post-menu"><a href="{{POST_LINK}}" title="short permalink to this answer" class="short-link">share</a></div></td><td class="post-signature" align="right"><div class="user-info "><div class="user-action-time">answered <span title="{{DATE}}" class="relativetime">{{REL_TIME}}</span></div><div class="user-gravatar32"></div><div class="user-details"><br></div></div></td><td class="post-signature" align="right"><div class="user-info user-hover"><div class="user-action-time"></div><div class="user-gravatar32"><a href="{{USER_LINK}}"><div class="gravatar-wrapper-32"><img {{img}} alt="" height="32" width="32"></div></a></div><div class="user-details"><a href="{{USER_LINK}}">{{NAME}}</a><br><span class="reputation-score" title="reputation score " dir="ltr">{{REP}}</span></div></div></td></tr></tbody></table></td></tr></tbody></table></div></div>
```

Comment: What can the second parameter be? Can it be `"rrfrburb"`? Also, when one shifts or reverses bits, does one do it for each individual letter, or the string as a whole? More test cases would make it clearer.

Comment: Do you mean shift or rotate? a leftshift in C will result in the leftmost bit being lost and the rightmost bit becoming zero. For a rightshift on an unsigned number the reverse happens. For a signed number I'm not sure if there is a universally defined behaviour for what gets shifted in for negative numbers (is it 0 or 1?) Either way, information is always lost when a shift is carried out, which isnt the case for a rotate.

Comment: FWIW there's [already one question based on that XKCD](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/17933/194).

Comment: @PeterTaylor Time to intruce an `xkcd`-tag?

Comment: @flawr, I don't think it would have any advantage over the existing ability to [search for 'xkcd'](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/search?q=xkcd+is%3Aquestion)

Comment: I've rewritten to be more compact, essentially by inlining the clarifications but also by adding some more (e.g. "Unicode" isn't an encoding). Please check that you don't think I've introduced any substantive changes.

Comment: @PeterTaylor You've written it correctly. I don't think it adding anything substantial enough to change anything except clarity is better.

Comment: Does the exact I/O format matter? For example, would an output of `['0', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '1']` be okay?

Comment: @KSFT I think I'm going to have to say no to that. Make it a string by joining it.

Comment: Wait, so there will be 4 differant answers depending on the input interpretaion right?

Comment: @Maltysen The question lists possible interpretations. You should use whatever makes your code shortest.

Comment: Please word your spec more carefully. Your question says that other **letters** may be used for instructions, but you accepted an answer that uses digits. Did you mean "characters" instead of "letters"?

Comment: @MartinBüttner Yes. I accepted it as it was the shortest. I've changed that now, and will make sure to not make that mistake again.

Comment: @Reticality Fair enough, I updated my answer accordingly (which is now the shortest).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## CJam, <s>34</s> 32 bytes

```
1l+256b2b1>l{~"11W:mm%!<>">4%~}/
```

It uses the following characters for instructions:

```
0: left rotation
1: right rotation
2: reverse
3: flip
```

The input is taking from STDIN with the word on the first line and the instruction string on the second line.

[Test it here.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/)

### Explanation

Getting the bit string is really just a matter of interpreting the character codes as the digits of a base-256 number (and getting its base-2 representation). The tricky thing is that the latter base conversion won't pad the result with 0s on the left. Therefore, I add a leading 1 to the initial input, and then split off that 1 again in the binary representation. As an example, if the input is `ab`, I turn that into an array `[1 'a 'b]`, interpret that as base-256 (characters are automatically converted to character codes), which is `90466` and the to base-2, which is `[1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0]`. Now if I just remove that leading `1` I've got the bitstream I'm looking for.

That's what this part of the code does:

```
1l+256b2b1>
```

Now I read the list of instructions and execute a block for each character in the instruction string:

```
l{...}/
```

The first thing to do is to evaluate the character and actual integers`0`, `1`, `2` or `3`. Now the real golfy magic... depending on the instruction I want to run a short piece of code that implements the operation:

```
Integer:  Code  Operation
0         1m<   "Left rotation";
1         1m>   "Right rotation";
2         W%    "Reverse";
3         :!    "Flip each bit";
```

I could store these in an array of blocks and choose the right block to run, but encoding them in a string is actually shorter:

```
"11W:mm%!<>">4%~
```

First, I use the integer associate with the instruction to slice off the beginning of the string. So for left rotation, the string is unchanged, for right rotation the first character is discarded and so on. Then I select every fourth character from the string, starting from the first, with `4%`. Notice how the four code snippets are distributed throughout the string. Finally I just evaluate the string as code with `~`.

The bit string is printed automatically at the end of the program.

Comment: Why `1m<` rather than `(+`? You're working on an array rather than a number, aren't you?

Comment: @Peter oh right, thanks. I'll fix that later.

Answer (score 2):

## CJam, 34 bytes

Another approach in CJam.

```
1l+256b2b1>l_S/,1&@f=_,,@f{W%~}\f=
```

The input text is on the first line and the instructions are on the second line.

Instructions:

```
)        Rotate left.
(        Rotate right.
 (space) Flip.
~        Reverse.
```

Comment: This is pretty clever. A shame that `f~` isn't implemented though, isn't it? ;)

Answer (score 2):

### Pyth 33

```
jku@[+eGPG+tGhG_Gms!dG)sHwsmjCk2z
```

Uses:

```
0    : rotate right
1    : rotate left
2    : reverse order
3    : flip values
```

[Pyth github](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth)

[Try it online here.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/)

This is a program that takes the string as it's first argument and the string of commands as the second argument. In the online version, you should give the strings separated by a newline, like so:

```
AbC
0321
```

Explanation:

```
                                    : z=input() (implicit)
jk                                  : join("", ...)
  u@[                 )sHw          : reduce(select from [...] the value at int(H), input(), ...)
     +eGPG                          : [ G[-1] + G[:1],
          +tGhG                     : G[1:] + G[1],
               _G                   : G[::-1],
                 ms!dG              : map(lambda d: int(not(d)), G) ]
                          smjCk2z   : first arg = sum(map(lambda k:convert_to_base(ord(k),2),z)
```

Something I couldn't quite squeeze in: Pyth's `reduce` automatically uses `G` for the previous value, and `H` for the next value.

Comment: Loosing your touch ? Just 1 byte shorter than CJam ?

Comment: @Optimizer Actually, I can beat that by using the same instructions. But I didn't think this would be valid because the challenge says "Other **letters** may be used instead of `lrfu`, but they must be clearly documented." (emphasis mine)

Answer (score 1):

## Matlab (166 bytes)

This uses letters `abcd` instead of `lrfu` respectively.

```
function D=f(B,C)
D=dec2bin(B,8)';
D=D(:);
g=@circshift;
for c=C
switch c-97
case 0
D=g(D,-1);
case 1
D=g(D,1);
case 2
D=char(97-D);
case 3
D=flipud(D);
end
end
D=D';
```

Some tricks used here to save space:

- Using `abcd` letters lets me subtract `97` once, and then the letters become `0`, `1`, `2`, `3`. This saves space in the `switch`-`case` clauses.
- Defining `circshift` as a one-letter anonymous function also saves space, as it's used twice.
- Since `D` consists of `'0'` and `'1'` characters (ASCII codes `48` and `49`),  the statement `D=char(97-D)` corresponds to inversion between `'0'` and `'1'` values. Note that this `97` has nothing to do with that referred to above.
- Complex-conjugate transpose `'` is used instead of transpose `.'`.

Answer (score 1):

## Scala - 192

```
def f(i:String,l:String)=(i.flatMap(_.toBinaryString).map(_.toInt-48)/:l){
case(b,'l')⇒b.tail:+b.head
case(b,'r')⇒b.last+:b.init
case(b,'f')⇒b.map(1-_)
case(b,'u')⇒b.reverse}.mkString
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python 2 - 179

```
b="".join([bin(ord(i))[2:]for i in input()])
for i in input():b=b[-1]+b[:-1]if i=="r"else b[1:]+b[0]if i=="l"else[str("10".find(j))for j in b]if i=="f"else b[::-1]
print"".join(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

#### C#, 418 bytes

```
using System;using System.Collections.Generic;using System.Linq;class P{string F(string a,string o){var f=new Dictionary<char,Func<string,IEnumerable<char>>>{{'l',s=>s.Substring(1)+s[0]},{'r',s=>s[s.Length-1]+s.Substring(0,s.Length-1)},{'u',s=>s.Reverse()},{'f',s=>s.Select(c=>(char)(97-c))}};return o.Aggregate(string.Join("",a.Select(c=>Convert.ToString(c,2).PadLeft(8,'0'))),(r,c)=>new string(f[c](r).ToArray()));}}
```

Formatted:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

class P
{
    string F(string a, string o)
    {
        // define string operations
        var f = new Dictionary<char, Func<string, IEnumerable<char>>>
        {
            {'l', s => s.Substring(1) + s[0]},
            {'r', s => s[s.Length - 1] + s.Substring(0, s.Length - 1)},
            {'u', s => s.Reverse()},
            {'f', s => s.Select(c => (char) (97 - c))}
        };
        // for each operation invoke f[?]; start from converted a
        return o.Aggregate(
            // convert each char to binary string, pad left to 8 bytes and join them
            string.Join("", a.Select(c => Convert.ToString(c, 2).PadLeft(8, '0'))),
            // invoke f[c] on result of prev operation
            (r, c) => new string(f[c](r).ToArray())
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript (E6), 163 <s>167</s>

Fully using the input flexibility, a named function with 2 array parameters.

- First parameter, array of bytes corresponding to 7 bit character codes
- Second parameter, array of bytes corresponding to ascii characters 'F','L','R','U' --> 70, 76, 82, 85

The function returns a character string composed of '1' and '0'

```js
F=(a,s,r='')=>
  a.map(c=>r+=(128|c).toString(2).slice(-7))-
  s.map(c=>a=c<71?a.map(c=>1-c):c<77?a.concat(a.shift):c<83?[a.pop(),...a]:a.reverse(),a=[...r])
  ||a.join('')
```

**Example** `f("b", "rfu")` translate to `F([98],[82,70,85])`, result is `0111001`

**Note** using character strings is so much longer in javascript! Byte count **186**

```js
F=(a,s,r='')=>
  [for(c of a)r+=(128|c.charCodeAt()).toString(2).slice(-7)]-
  [for(c of(a=[...r],s))a=c<'G'?a.map(c=>1-c):c<'M'?a.concat(a.shift):c<'S'?[a.pop(),...a]:a.reverse()]
  ||a.join('')
```

**Example** `F("b", "RFU")`, result is `0111001` again

Answer (score 0):

### J, 164

```
([: >@:}. (([: }. >&{.) ; >@:{.@:>@:{. 128!:2 >@:}.)^:({.@:$@:>@:{.))@:(>@:((<;._1 ' 1&|."1 _1&|."1 -. |."1') {~ 'lrfu' i. 0&({::)@:]) ; ;@:([: (8$2)&#: a. i. 1&({::)))
```

Formatted:

```
nextop=:([: }. >&{.)
exec=: (>@:{.@:>@:{.) apply"1 >@:}.
times=: ({.@:$@:>@:{.)
gapply=: [: >@:}. (nextop ; exec)^:(times) f.

tobin=: ;@:([: (8#2)&#:(a.i.1&{::))
g=:'1&|.';'_1&|.';'-.';'|.'
tog =:  g {~ ('lrfu' i. 0&{::@:])
golf=: gapply @: (>@:tog;tobin)  f.
```

Example

```
golf ('rfu';'b')
0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1


golf ('lruuff';'b')
0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0

(8#2)#: 98
0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0

golf ('lruuff';'AB')
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0

tobin '';'AB'
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0
```

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby, 151

```ruby
f=->i,s{s.chars.inject(i.unpack("B*")[0]){|a,c|
a.reverse! if c==?u
a.tr!"01","10" if c==?f
a<<a.slice!(1..-1) if c==?l
a<<a.slice!(0..-2) if c==?r
a}}
```

Fairly straightforward. Loops trough the characters in `s` and performs an action for any of them.

Answer (score 0):

### Python 2, 142

```
j="".join
f=lambda S,I:reduce(lambda s,i:[s[1:]+s[0],s[-1]+s[:-1],s[::-1],j([`1^int(c)`for c in s])][int(i)],I,j([bin(ord(c))[2:]for c in S]))
```

Similar to my pyth answer in approach: I build a list of all the strings and index into it based on the value of the instruction string that I iterate over using reduce.

Uses:

```
0  ->  Rotate left
1  ->  Rotate right
2  ->  Reverse order
3  ->  Invert bits
```